# javascript: fetch blocked by CORS policy because of wildcard

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, wildcard

I am trying to use the following api endpoint using fetch:

`https://api.guerrillamail.com/ajax.php?f=check_email&ip=${ip}&agent=${agent}`
([outdated documentation](https://www.guerrillamail.com/GuerrillaMailAPI.html))

When I set `credentials: 'include'` I get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.guerrillamail.com/ajax.php?...' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

I have to set the flag in order to submit a cookie for authentication. 
After googling this problem for 1++ hour, my understanding is the following:
CORS has to be server side allowed to be able to make "none simple" request to an other domain e.g. `localhost => guerrillamail.com` to prevent abuse, a variable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` has to be set to the domains that should be allowed to send requests. A valid option is "*", which means that ALL origins are ok.
For some reason it is not ok though in combination with the `credentials: 'include` flag.

Do you have any ideas why this wouldnt be allowed?
Do you know what I have to do, in order to to do the request?
And is my understanding about this correct?

Comment: The api.guerramail.com server should send that header. If you're not in control of that server you need to contact them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you're referencing no longer applies. In that old documentation, the API was made available over HTTP rather than HTTPS. CORS doesn't apply to HTTP and wouldn't have been a problem.

In the [latest documention](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qw5KQP1j57BPTDmms5nspe-QAjNEsNg8cQHpAAycYNM/edit?hl=en#), that API is provided over HTTPS. To deal with the CORS requirement, they also removed the need for cookies, changing it to `subscr_token` and `sid_token` parameters sent as part of the request:

> version 1.5, 30th May 2011
>   - Removed the requirement for cookies, added subscr_token and sid_token parameters

Comment: You write: _CORS doesn't apply to HTTP_. Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @jub0bs Many modern web-related standards are living standards, including CORS, and so old answers may no longer apply.

Comment: Sure, but old versions of the CORS standard are still available online, and I see no evidence in them of CORS not applying to HTTP. Could it be the case that your claim was never correct?

Comment: @jub0bs Feel free to link a reference indicating such. Also, keep in mind that implementation can and did differ from spec and that how it differed evolved over time. Should be able to find something in the Chromium or Firefox trackers about the CORS-related updates.

Comment: I feel like the onus to prove your claim should be on you :)